# 11 year old leaking or wetting pants while laughing

Tags: pre-teen, fears

My 11 year old daughter has "leaked" or wet her pants (small amount) while laughing hard.  She has become irrationally fearful to the point where she quit soccer and doesn't want to do anything where it might happen again I don't know how to help her with this.  I don't think it is a physiological problem it is normal for this to happen occasionally.  She is getting more and more anxious as school approaches-please help

Comment: This sounds like an issue that should be discussed with a doctor. In the meantime, you could give her feminine hygiene pads to protect soaking through her clothes.

Comment: I did give her the pads-and maybe you are right thanks

Comment: I'm curious to know why you are asking this exact same question again. If you did not find the answers to the previous question helpful, please explain why in an edit to your original question. Thanks.